# Information Security on a lost android phone

Tags: android, physical, account-security, tracking

Recently, my android mobile phone was lost/stolen. I had logged into several applications such as Facebook, Paytm, etc. Thus, there are chances that my personal/ transaction details might be leaked.

I tried Google Timeline & Android Device Manager. It shows data about the last connection to the internet was before it was lost. I believe it may have been:

1. Switched off, Or
2. Not connect to the network, Or even worse
3. Phone is factory-reset.

I've no tracking software installed separately except for ADM.

What options do I have for remote security and tracking my device?

Comment: After the fact, or for new phone?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to "remotely secure" your phone is to track it with ADM.

If you can't track the phone, while you are 100% sure you have ADM on and installed there is a chance that it has been reset. This also means they've wiped most of the installed apps and accounts. So they should not have access to your accounts connected to the apps.

But in case they didn't factory-reset your phone, your info would still be on the phone. If this is the case I would recommend you to change your passwords of all the know apps you used.

Comment: Also, since it doesn't always happen automatically, "un-link" any accounts that have device links like Dropbox, etc. so that in case the device is accessed, the apps will not lead them to your online information.

Comment: Thank you for adding this @JeffMeden I forgot to mention this!